# Query data with datetimeoffset type in pyobdc fails on linux

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, pyodbc

I have a table in a sql server database, where time is stored using the datetimeoffset datatype.

All worked fine on windows 10, but when I moved my code to a docker container (ubuntu 1604, python 3.7.6 and pyobdc 4.0.30). OBDC drivers added by Dockerfile with

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
```

I then started getting the following selecting data a datetimetoffset field, eg `SELECT date FROM ...`:

```
ProgrammingError: ('ODBC SQL type -155 is not yet supported.  column-index=0  type=-155', 'HY106')
```

My current workaround is the convert the datetime field to a date in sql with `SELECT convert(datetime, date) FROM ...`

I expect it is a limitation of the OBDC drivers on Linux.

I would prefer not updating the sql, so I wonder if there are alternatives to the OBDC drivers I use or other options

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/134#issuecomment-452893948